# Jmeter form_key showing form_key=deleted

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I have a **post request** in which the jmeter **form_key** is showing

**form_key=deleted**

```
e.g-
```

**POST data:
    form_key=deleted**

```
Is the request correct?
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass correct value of form_key. which you will get the in response of previous samplers. use Regular expression Extractor to extract the value of form_key.

> "form_key"="(.+?)"

Comment: I have used regex this is the result of my debug samplerJMeterVariables:
Content-Encoding=UTF-8/
FORM_KEY=4CjsISvy3jZlM8Xt
FORM_KEY_PDP=deleted
FORM_KEY_PDP_g=1
FORM_KEY_PDP_g0=<input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="deleted" />
FORM_KEY_PDP_g1=deleted

Answer (score 0):

Add HTTP Cookie Manager to the jmeter and change value in dropdown from standard to default .[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rUlL.png)